# Google Apps Script - Chart Service: table size, column format

Tags: google-apps-script, format, google-visualization

I use the Google Chart Service to create a table in Google Apps Script for my web app.
Now I have 2 problems:

1. When I add more rows and columns, The columns' width is getting smaller until the point were scrollbars appear. I added a code example. Can I change/increase the (maximum) displayed size of the chart, so that there are no scrollbars?
2. I need a string-column, which is aligned to the right. The default is a aligned to the left for string columns. How can I change this? And are there more options to modify the format of the table (text size, colors, bold etc.)?

   ```
   function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();

   var data = Charts.newDataTable()
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Name")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Gender")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Age")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
   .addRow(["Michael", "Male", 12, 5])
   .addRow(["Michael", "Male", 12, 5])
   .addRow(["Elisa", "Female", 20, 7])
   .addRow(["Robert", "Male", 7, 3])
   .addRow(["John", "Male", 54, 2])
   .addRow(["Jessica", "Female", 22, 6])
   .addRow(["Aaron", "Male", 3, 1])
   .addRow(["Margareth", "Female", 42, 8])
   .addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
   .addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
   .addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
   .addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
   .addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
   .addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
   .build();

   var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(data)
   .build();

   app.add(tableChart);

   return app;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*About p.1.* There are two ways to change a chart width and height. The 1st one is to use the [setDimensions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tablechartbuilder#setDimensions) method of the `TableChartBuilder` class. A disadvantage of this method is that impossible to set width/height in the page width/height percentage. The 2nd way is to use the [setOption](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tablechartbuilder#setOption) methof of the same class. This method has no the disadvantage. The following code demonstrates it.

*About p.2.* Unfortunately, now it is not possible to align columns of the Table Chart. As far as I know it is even impossible to align columns of the [GWT Table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) which is under the hood of the Table Chart. You are free to create a feature request on the [GAS issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) about this lack.

```
function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();

var data = Charts.newDataTable()
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Name")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Gender")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Age")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
.addRow(["Michael", "Male", 12, 5])
.addRow(["Michael", "Male", 12, 5])
.addRow(["Elisa", "Female", 20, 7])
.addRow(["Robert", "Male", 7, 3])
.addRow(["John", "Male", 54, 2])
.addRow(["Jessica", "Female", 22, 6])
.addRow(["Aaron", "Male", 3, 1])
.addRow(["Margareth", "Female", 42, 8])
.addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
.addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
.addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
.addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
.addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
.addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
.build();

var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(data);

//tableChart.setDimensions(1200, 100); // Uncomment this line if you wish to set dimentions in pixels.
tableChart.setOption('width', '100%');
tableChart.setOption('height', '100%');  


app.add(tableChart.build());

return app;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to scale the legend?. Setting width and height does not zoom labels and legend. I tried with theme maximized but it changes the labels inside. Any thoughts?