# Google app script - Chart Service / TableChart: column width & row height

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, column-width

How to set width of a TableChart is explained in [Google Apps Script - Chart Service: table size, column format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553803/google-app-script-chart-service-table-size-column-format).

What I need to do is control the absolute or relative sizes of columns and rows of the TableChart when it's displayed via a UiApp.

Starting with the script provided in megabyte1024's answer to that previous problem, how would one make the four "Donuts Eaten" columns each just 10% of the table width, say?

Can we control width by pixels and %? What are the control parameters for row height?

Comment: It's not possible yet. When you set a table height, it will distribute the columns according to how wide the content is and rows will always be the same size. If you don't need the filtering ability of a chart, you can create your own table with UiApp's FlexTable:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_flextable